# What are some good methods to finding a heuristic for the A* algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, heuristics, shortest-path, a-star

You have a map of square tiles where you can move in any of the 8 directions. Given that you have function called `cost(tile1, tile2)` which tells you the cost of moving from one adjacent tile to another, how do you find a heuristic function h(y, goal) that is both admissible and consistent? Can a method for finding the heuristic be generalized given this setting, or would it be vary differently depending on the `cost` function?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Amit's tutorial is one of the best I've seen on A* [(Amit's page)](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html#S7). You should find some very useful hint about heuristics on this page .

Here is the quote about your problem :

> On a square grid that allows 8 directions of movement, use Diagonal distance (L∞).

Comment: This still depends on your cost function for moving to an adjacent square.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the cost function.

There are a couple of common heuristics, such as [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) (the absolute distance between two tiles on a 2d plane) and [Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) (the sum of the absolute x and y deltas).  But these assume that the actual cost is never less than a certain amount.  Manhattan distance is ruled out if your agent can efficiently move diagonally (i.e. the cost of moving to a diagonal is less than 2).  Euclidean distance is ruled out if the cost of moving to a neighbouring tile is less than the absolute distance of that move (e.g. maybe if the adjacent tile was "downhill" from this one).

### Edit

Regardless of your cost function, you always have an admissable and consistent heuristic in `h(t1, t2) = -∞`.  It's just not a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the heuristic is dependent on the cost function, in a couple of ways. First, it must be in the same units. Second, you can't have a lower-cost path through actual nodes than the cost of the heuristic.

In the real world, used for things like navigation on a road network, your heuristic might be "the time a car would take on a direct path at 1.5x the speed limit." The cost for each road segment would use the actual speed limit, which will give a higher cost.

So, what is your cost function between tiles? Is it based on physical properties, or defined outside of your graph?

Comment: A better heuristic is 'the time a car would take if there was a motorway (road with the highest speed limit) in a straight line to the destination'. There is no need to apply the factor of 1.5.