# chosing a* heuristic function

Tags: c#, a-star, heuristics

I'm still trying to figure out how and why my heuristics choices affect the search time of my a* implementation.

I have my map as follows ( not exact size ):

```
###########
#         #
# # # # # #
#         #
# # # # # #
#         #
```

I chose my heuristics as

```
option 1: h = abs(n.x - target.x) + abs(n.y - target.y)
option 2: h = 2*(abs(n.x- target.x) + abs(n.y - target.y))
```

with `option 1`, the algorithm runs relatively fine until I have to move from top to bottom, and in that case it takes long to come up with the path.

with `option 2`, the `option 1` time is improved by around 90%.

I tried to read about overestimation/underestimation, and I couldn't come up with a clear explanation.

What could be the reason? also, are my choices reasonable?

Comment: Why not choose a Euclidean distance? It’s been a while since I worked with this but given a 2D map space, a Euclidean distance should give an optimal heuristic.

Comment: You should also test heuristics with other maps too, the best heuristic would be the one that performs best by taking the average time (steps) of all maps

Comment: I would also suggest Euclidean distance, it gives a decent estimate of the remaining path, while being easily computable, therefore fast. Also, it is admissible.

Comment: @konrad I thought manhattan would be more appropriate since I can't move diagonally.

Comment: I tried Euclidean distance and it's even worse.

Comment: have a look at Jump Point Search

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5687914/2679529) answer. There is a [link](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html#S7) to a nice tutorial that explains and gives *rules of thumb* about which heuristics should be chosen for different types of problems, followed by a friendly explanation of those techniques.

Comment: from that link that's where I got the idea of multiplying option 1 by some  D. and I picked 2.